TypeScript in VSCode Not Immediately Recognizing Installed Libraries
I've been experiencing an issue with TypeScript within VSCode. Every time I install a new library (via npm install), TypeScript does not seem to immediately recognize the library.
For example, after installing the query-string library and trying to import it, I initially get an error:
import queryString from 'query-string'; // TypeScript reports module not found
However, these errors go away after I manually restart the TypeScript server.
I was expecting TypeScript to automatically recognize the new libraries immediately after installation without needing to restart the server. From my understanding, the TypeScript language server should re-index the changes after an npm install.
I'm currently using VSCode v1.90.2, TypeScript v5.5.2, and Node.js v20.10.0.
Has anyone else experienced this issue, and is there any configuration change or workaround that would allow TypeScript to automatically recognize newly installed libraries without manual server restarts?
Thanks in advance for your help.

"Has anyone else experienced this issue" yes but only related to using yarn pnp with it's non node_module caching thing. I've never had it in "normal" projects, and it is definitely not how it is supposed to work. I'd try potentially reinstalling vscode if you can't get traction any other way.

Apparently, the issue was caused by this line of my user settings.json:
"typescript.tsserver.experimental.enableProjectDiagnostics": true
It tells TypeScript to check your entire project for errors rather than only checking the files that you have open, which was a pretty useful feature but... not worth the price I was paying for it (everything "felt" slower and a bit clunky, but I didn't notice it right away - probably I installed something else that was not compatible with that experimental setting.
